# You are given a binary string S consisting of O's and 1's

Tags: data-structures

You are given a binary string S consisting of O's and 1's. You have to tell whether it is possible to split the string into exactly K substrings such that each character belongs to exactly one substring and the decimal value of each substring is the same.

Determine whether it is possible to split the string S into exactly K substrings such that each character belongs to exactly one substring and the decimal value of each substring is the same.

Example:
S: 10100101
K: 2
Result: true
S can be split into K parts, 101 and 00101, which have same decimal value

Comment: Maybe I'm just tired but this question just doesn't make any sense to me. Can you give an example of the data?

Comment: @Kevin let's say we have a string = 10100101 and k = 2. Now we divide this string into two parts such that 101 and 00101 which have same decimal value.

Answer (score 0):

We can ignore the '0's as leading zeroes but we can't ignore '1's. So, first we need to check if we can divide the ones in k substring. Let's say, we can divide the '1's and each substring contains p number of ones.

Similarly, we can not ignore the '0's which comes after the last '1'. So, each segment must have the same number of trailing '0's as the last one.

We build substrings by following these two conditions and checking if the substrings are equal. Because with two '1's and two trailing '0's in each substring you can have 10100 and 1100 which leads to different decimal values.

Here is my C++ code

```
bool isSplitPossible(string str, int k) {
    int ones = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < str.length() ; i++) {
        if(str[i] == '1') {
            ones++;
        }
    }
   if(ones%k != 0) {
       // We can not divide all the ones into k segments
       // so its not possible to split
       return false;
   }
   int segOnes = ones/k;
   // We can ignore leading zeroes but cant ignore zeroes
   // that comes after the last '1'. So, each k segment have same
   // amount of trailing zeroes
   int trailingZero = 0;
   for(int i = str.length()-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
       if(str[i] == '1') {
            break;
       }
       trailingZero++;
    }
    string prevSegment = "";

    int oneCnt,zeroCnt,segCount ;
    oneCnt = zeroCnt = segCount = 0;
    string sub = "";
    // Now we try to create segments maintaing two previous conditions
    for(int i = 0 ; i < str.length() ; i++) {
        if(str[i] == '1') {
            sub.push_back('1');
            oneCnt++;
        }
        else {
            // We only count trailing zeroes, if oneCnt is not equal segOnes,
            // it is leading zero or middle zero and we ignore
            if(oneCnt == segOnes) {
                sub.push_back('0');
                zeroCnt++;
            }
        }
        if(oneCnt == segOnes && trailingZero == zeroCnt) {
            // Got a segment, match it with prev segment if it is not first
            if(prevSegment.length() == 0 ) {
                prevSegment = sub;
            }
            else {
               if(prevSegment != sub) {
                    return false;
               }
            }
           segCount++;
           oneCnt = zeroCnt = 0;
           sub = "";
        }
    }
    if(segCount != k) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool isSplitPossible(string str, int k) {
int n = str.length();
int allone = 0;
for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {
    if(str[i] == '1') {
        allone++;
    }
}
if(allone%k != 0) {
   return false;
}
int segOnes = allone/k;

int trailingZero = 0;
for(int i = str.length()-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
   if(str[i] == '1') {
        break;
   }
   trailingZero++;
}
string prevSegment = "";

int oneCnt,zeroCnt,segCount ;
oneCnt = zeroCnt = segCount = 0;
string sub = "";

for(int i = 0 ; i < str.length() ; i++) {
    if(str[i] == '1') {
        sub.push_back('1');
        oneCnt++;
    }
    else {
        if(oneCnt == segOnes) {
            sub.push_back('0');
            zeroCnt++;
        }
        else(oneCnt !=0){
            sub.push_back('0');
        }
    }
    if(oneCnt == segOnes && trailingZero == zeroCnt) {
        if(prevSegment.length() == 0 ) {
            prevSegment = sub;
        }
        else {
           if(prevSegment != sub) {
                return false;
           }
        }
       segCount++;
       oneCnt = zeroCnt = 0;
       sub = "";
    }
}
if(segCount != k) {
    return false;
}
return true;
}
```